# Parse: deleting object value in column using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've used Parse successfully in other apps before but never used the delete function. I'm trying to delete a value ( an alphabetical letter) in a column (column title is 'letter') associated with a user in Parse. I'm using Swift. The code is finding the correct value as evident via a println in the deletion code, but nothing is happening after the remove and save functions are executed. The value is still there in the column. And I'm not getting any Parse errors. The code is below. Any help, as always, will be greatly appreciated.

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "game")

    query.whereKey("player", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser())

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if !(error != nil) {
            for object in objects {

                var myLetter = object["letter"]! as String

                println("The object for key letter is \(myLetter)") //This prints the correct letter in the current user's Letter column

                PFUser.currentUser().removeObjectForKey("letter")

                PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                                (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                                if (success) {
                                    // The object has been saved.
                                    println("success")

                                } else {
                                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                                    println(error)
                                }
                            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are creating a new Parse query and deleting it locally as opposed to retrieving the item and then deleting it. So, retrieve the item you want to delete and then call the deleteInBackground method.